# Antenna Preprocessor - where to specify my defines?

Tags: java, preprocessor

Am trying to use Antenna preprocessor in eclipse. To define a variable, either I am going to go to GUI of antenna or define in the very class where I have ifdef. I wish to have a separate file to list all my defines. How do I do that? I tried to create another class Defines.java just to keep the defines. And I imported this class in my java class which has //#ifdef. But it does not work. Please help!